# 'unknown data type' error in write.dta in R

Tags: r, export

trying to convert an R dataframe to a Stata .dta. Had good luck with this same data before creating a bunch of new variables with mapvalues [plyr]. All of these are factors, re-coded and cleaned from variables elsewhere in the dataset. Now just trying to export what I've done to a .dta file...made sure the data is of class 'data.frame' but keep getting errors:

```
> dfmen<-data.frame(men)
> write.dta(data = 'dfmen', file = 'mento81.dta')

> Error in write.dta(data = "dfmen", file = "mento81.dta") : 
  The object "dataframe" must have class data.frame

> class(dfmen)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Anybody know what's going on?

THANKS!!

Comment: Perhaps not a typo but it is the equivalent, hence the vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter should be the data.frame itself, not the data.frame name.

```
write.dta(data = dfmen, file = 'mento81.dta')
```

should work.